# Streamlit: space/blank space in sidebar

Tags: python, streamlit

In streamlit, I want to achieve a gap in the sidebar without the free space containing a clickable cell.

I tried this but it makes a space like shown in screen provided below clickable:

`menu = st.sidebar.radio("Menu", ["1", "2", " ", "3"])`

[image: SCREEN]

Comment: Yeah, that will create blank space. Why do want show space between option?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite css with following syntax.
try below syntax:

```
import streamlit as st
st.markdown("""
    <style>
    [role=radiogroup]{
        gap: 3rem;
    }
    </style>
    """,unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

U can get classname from inspect elements, using those classname u can overwrite their property